# "-ый" после числа

Tags: числительные, наращение

Когда не нужны дополнения после числа, вроде "1-ый"?

Comment: Наращение "-ый" всегда ошибочно. Корректно: 1-й.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если пишутся количественные числительные: "роман в 30 главах";
При записи календарных дат;
Если присутствует римская цифра;
В номерах, если родовое слово предшествует числительльному: "В серии 8".

Answer (score 2):

**I.** Наращение (буквенное падежное окончание) используется в записи порядковых числительных. Правильно будет так:
**1-й** (перв**ый**) вагон; **12-й** (двенадцат**ый**) этаж; **125-й** (сто двадцать пят**ый**) день; **14-й** (четырнадцат**ый**) ряд.
Наращение ***-ый*** после числительного **неправильно.**

**II.** **Наращение не требуется** в следующих случаях.

1. В записи количественных числительных:
   подвиг 28 панфиловцев; сочинение в 15 томах; после 20 лет брака.
2. При записи календарных чисел, если слово "год" или название месяца следует за числом:
   15 июля 1961 года; в 2018 году; 24 декабря.
3. Если число обозначено римской цифрой:
   загадочная смерть Карла XII; итоги XIV съезда; XXI век.
4. В номерах томов, глав, страниц, иллюстраций, таблиц, приложений и т. п., **если родовое слово** (том, глава) **предшествует числительному**:
   на с. 195, в т. 9, в табл. 10, в прил. 8.

[Буквенные наращения после цифр](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)